# why is global variable not accessible even if local variable is defined later in code

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, local-variables

why does the following code segment generate the following output?

code segment:

```
var a = 10;
function(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 5;
}
```

output:

```
undefined
```

Comment: [Javascript Scope And Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html#declarations_names_and_hoisting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because variable is hoisted at top and in your function you have declared the variable var a = 5 which is same as following:

```
var a = 10;
function(){
    var a; // a = undefined
    console.log(a);//a is not defined so outputs undefined
    a = 5;
    console.log(a);//a is now 5 so outputs 5
}
```

And in your function scope var is being declared it doesn't see global variable but local variable i.e. var a and which is undefined.